# How can I start an interactive HEREDOC from a script?

Tags: sh, heredoc, mutt

I use this to start a HEREDOC, type the text and finish up by placing a single dot in the last line:

```
mutt -s "foo" -- bar@example.com << .
```

The same from within a script will fail due to syntax error.

(**sh**/**zsh**/... are expecting to provide the entire HEREDOC within the script itself.)

**How can I achieve the desired effect regardless?**

Comment: In general, you cannot. It's not the here document that is interactive, it's the fact that you are entering the entire *command* in an interactive shell. You could simply let `mutt` read from the inherited standard input if nothing else in the script requires standard input.

Comment: Can you give an example regarding reading from stdin? I currently don't see how that could be used to achieve a similar workflow.

Comment: You just don't give any here document to `mutt`; when `mutt` runs, it will block until you type in the message, then use Control-D (or whatever your terminal requires) to send EOF. `mutt` will continue, but nothing else in your script will be able to read from standard input, as you have effectively closed it, so it isn't exactly identical to using a here document.

Comment: In my case the chepner's solution doesn't work. But `cat | mutt -s "foo -- bar@example.com` does. cat's stdout is piped to mutt's stdin. and cat waits for input from stdin if there's no file file or other input provided.

Comment: @chepner When `<<` is present, is the behavior of `cat` is modified? For example, I can add `cat << EOF; hello world; EOF` in a bash script and it will not be interactive. But if I write `cat; hello world` in a bash script, then it behaves interactively waiting for me to type something.

Comment: `cat` is trying to read from whatever file descriptor it is given for standard input. The difference is between the temporary file descriptor that `bash` writes directly to for the here document, and the terminal device that *you* need to write to in the interactive shell.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar to start an ssh session with my dotfile from local